# windows cannot find %windir%\System32\msdt.exe

Tags: windows-7, path

I'm having this issue when i'm on Device and Printers and i'm trying to load this particular path.

I think my disk / bios had just went kaputz. It somehow forgot where the system paths are like %windir%.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in the advanced system properties. You may just want to add c:\windows\system32 to the path, or mak sure the %windir% variable is set as in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Yeah i can't get that to load either. lol my disk really got corrupt

Comment: Yes, if you cannot do those basic things, you are probably hosed. Even chkdsk probably won't do it, and I am not sure I would trust that to repair it all anyway.

Comment: hmm i was able to access it manually by cmd C:\Windows\System32\SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe but it won't save any of the variables.

Comment: Well thanks anyways. I think i figured it. I'll mark this as solved anyways.

Comment: It got fixed! I didn't know i turned on system restore. It fixed it that way (for the record). Luckily, i recently did a windows update and i had a restore point. Thanks for your concern!

Comment: Very cool, but very strange too. Glad you got it.

Comment: System restore is the silent hero.  I never understand why people turn it off. . .

Comment: @surfasb Very true. I think maybe when they are removing viruses, and then they forget to turn it back on.

Comment: From my perspective, I always see people complaining cause it uses diskspace. . . **that they aren't using**.  Gawd forbid that you use more than 25% of your computer. . .

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Here is what I did:

I directly open `C:\Windows\System32\SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` file.

1. Copied Path variable value into Notepad++
2. Search/replace ; with \r\n (select extended search mode)
3. Now I can see each item clearly in its own line. I found few duplicate items because certain software Re-Installed multiple times. What I noticed I had duplicate entries like below:

   - C:\PROGRA~1\MI3EDC~1\100\Tools\Binn\
   - C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\

Both lines are essentially same but somehow stuff like this can easily cause you headache. I removed duplicate content from PATH and it started working fine.

Hope this helps.